# why success: function() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm fairly new to J-QUERY and JavaScript.  I have several forms that use some JavaScript to collect data and submit to an asp page to handle the request (edit user data, add information, delete, etc) which calls a T-SQL procedure.  The process works fine but I need to add some checks and alert messages but I'm unsuccessful.  Here is a sample

```
$("#add-user-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 420,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Add User': function () {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');`enter code here`
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(loginname, "Login Name", 3, 10);
            if (bValid) {
                var statusdataString = '?section=adduser&loginname=' + loginname.val() + '&fullname=' + fullname.val() + '&type=' + type.val();
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "admin.asp" + statusdataString
                });
            }
            window.location.reload();
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
    }
});
```

This is the asp section that is invoked

```
if (section = "adduser") then
   edituser_sql =  "Exec add_user "  & "'" & request("loginname") & "','" &       
   request("fullname") & "'," & request("type") 
   Conn.execute edituser_sql
   Conn.close
   set Conn = nothing 
   set dsn = nothing 

end if
```

Now here are my issues:

1. I need to put an alert once all of this is done to say "user added" or "Duplicate user" etc.  I have tried adding it after success: like so

   $.ajax({ 
   type: "GET", 
   url: "admin.asp"+statusdataString,
   success: function(){alert("something")}

   });

but it doesn't work.  I have also try to save the results the procedure returns, which tells me if they user was added or not, and then within the asp code do this

```
if results= -1 then 
%>
<Script type="text/JavaScript">
alert("something");
</script>
<%
```

But that doesn't work either.  I think I understand the process but I'm not sure how all of this code works, just bits and pieces.  Your help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason your success handler is not working is because the web service call is not successful.

Try adding a `error:` parameter to your ajax call similar to my example. I am using a POST to a asmx service, but you can copy the `error:` part into your function.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "../webserviceurl",
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "  application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            // Show any returned message alerts
            return;
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert("error" + ex.toString());
        }
    });
```

Then you can debug the cause of the web request failure.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have tried that before and I always get the error, even tho the asp page calls the sql proc correctly and add the user.  Now I get a different error , it is [object] and that is what it is.

Comment: @user1484083 Is the `[object]` in the alert? add a .toString() to the `ex` to see the error message, or inspect it in firebug, IE developer tools, etc.

Comment: I did exactly that and not getting anything anymore.  I removed it and still nothing.  My asp code works and calls the proc fine just can't tell send the user any messages.  I'm thinking about removing this code since it doesn't work.  Success or error nothing works.  How do you guys get this junk to work?

Comment: You need to remove `window.location.reload();` right after your ajax call, the screen is being reloaded before the async ajax call completes. That is why `success` or `error` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would have your ASP script return some XML or JSON describing what you want the page to do instead of your asp page outputting some javacsript.

EDIT: I have made the ASP code a little more specific and I have also changed the javascript to reflect a little better what you might do to manipulate the page if you were using, say, knockoutjs to modify the page.

In your ajax function, you could do this:

```
'Add User': function () {
    //....stuff you did...
    $.ajax({
        url: "YourUrl....",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status) {
                alert("User added!");
                //do some stuff with response.user
                //if using knockoutjs, just add it to an observable which you would have
                //previously put in the class myViewModel (users is an observable array)
                //this would magically make it appear in your user list
                myViewModel.users.push(new UserModel(response.user));
            }
            else {
                alert("User not created");
            }
        }
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
///the rest of your function
```

Also, you would have to get rid of the page reload part.

Your ASP would return some JSON formatted as follows to be compatible with what I just wrote:

```
%>
{
    status : <% response.write(response > -1) %>
    user : { <% response.write(aStringInWhichYouHavePutSomeInfoAboutTheUser) %> }
}
%>
```

Also, I do not know much ASP, so I am guessing on the syntax above based on what I know :p

Comment: Well, if i get rid of the page reload, then how would I see the new user after it was added? I don't know how to write an asp code to return some JSON formatted as you mentioned above.  Also, I don't understand why i can't include some javascript within this asp code? is it because it is ajaxed?

Comment: The point of ajax is so that the page doesn't have to reload. You would pass back enough data to the page that it should be able to construct a new entry in your users list. You could execute the javascript, but technically you would have just been doing ahah (async html and http) and you would have to manually add the script into your page. As for the json, you can either have your page output a string you have formatted to be json or have the page fill in a json template.

Comment: I was doing that but it didn't look good and a lot of code I had to write to post up the new data, reload can do that in a sec, so I must use it or something that will refresh the page.  How do i pass back data?  remember i'm very new, I don't know how to post back data from asp to JS or ajax.  is there a reason why I can just type this in my asp "if results = -1 then %> <script type="text/javascript> alert('user added') </script> <%  more asp code  %>  This would solve my problem so why is this not work? or how could i make it work.maybe I should go old school with pure asp code and some jS?

Comment: It doesn't work because whatever the AJAX request returns is not being  processed. AJAX doesn't load onto the page; it loads into an object that is parsed by your 'success' in the ajax handler. Sometimes it does create a lot of code to have to add elements. One way around this is to use a framework like knockoutjs (knockoutjs.com) or backbone (backbonejs.org) with jQuery to handle adding items automatically to the page when you do something AJAXy. I prefer knockoutjs just because its less code.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include an example of what you could do on the server side to output JSON and what you could do on the client javascript side to modify your page if you were using a framework to change your page for you. Also another note about refreshing the page: The location of your page refresh would prevent the ajax event from ever finishing since the page would reload before the AJAX got its response back from the server. If you really really needed the page to refresh, you would probably want to put it after everything else in the success function.

Comment: I didn't work and here: ASP code  
RSUser.Open "exec delete_user '" & request("loginname") & "'" , Conn,1,3 %>
{ status : <% response.write(RSuser.fields("results")) %> }<% 
End if    then I did this    $.ajax({ type: "post", url: "admin.asp"+statusdataString, dataType: "json", success: function(response){if(response.status){alert("user deleted");} else {alert("user not created");}}, error: function(error){alert("error" + error );}   }); Could never get to success, always error [object] but the proc is executed correctly.  I don't think i will be able to wortk this without an expert

Comment: Why can't I add a javascript within my asp code to print whatever alert I want however I want it?  Can anyone answer this?  Why can't I when the asp ajaxed, after I call the procedure, i write an asp statement to test some returned value by the procedure and use javascript to alert whatever I want? it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Well it looks like I have found a way around it.  I simply removed the ajax and replace to with a redirect to the page I want and now I can write all the alerts I need in my asp,  I'm still interested figuring out this issue but for now, I'm happy with the way things are.

Comment: I also want to thank very one who helped me, so thank you for your time